# Excel Stripping off Leading Zeros in a View

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, excel-formula, view

I have a SQL Server view I'm pulling into an excel macro workbook. However, one of the date fields is being treated as a number by excel and it's leading 0 is subsequently being stripped off. Is there a datatype I can convert my date field to in SQL so that excel does not strip off it's leading zero when the view is imported into the workbook?

Comment: Your description of the situation doesn't really explain the method you are using to bring the SQL data in. Typically, the cell would receive the raw data and cell formatting would apply a leading zero to a date. If you wanted to bring it in as text (not really a preferred action) then you could rewrite the view as something like `SELECT CHAR(39)+CONVERT(varchar(10), [myDate]) FROM ...` but that is interpretive of how SQL is going to output the date.

Comment: Are your system's Regional Settings for **Short Date** set for d/m/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy (or m/d/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy)? Setting the regional setting for the system (which Excel reads and uses) may be sufficient to get your leading zero on dates.

Comment: to keep leading zero into excel put a ' into sql e.g.  select '''+column showwithzero from table

Answer (score 1):

How are you pulling the data in? AFAIK there's no Excel-wide setting to keep the leading zeros, however there are ways to keep them, or to add them back:

From [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Keep-leading-zeros-in-number-codes-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7#__toc260929206)
If you're using the import wizard,

> Convert the number to text when you import text data
>
> In Step 3 of the Text Import Wizard (On the Data tab, in the Get
>   External Data group, click From Text), you can select the column of
>   data that contains the credit card number, and then explicitly choose
>   a Text column data format.

Alternatively, if you already imported the data and there's a pattern/structure to it, you can create a custom format:

> Use a custom format to keep the leading zeros
>
> If you want to resolve the issue just within the workbook because it's
>   not used by other programs as a data source, you can use a custom or a
>   special format to keep the leading zeros. This works for number codes
>   that contain fewer than 16 digits,
>
> In addition, you can separate some of the digits in your number codes
>   with dashes by adding these dashes to the custom format. For example,
>   to make a phone number more readable, you can add a dash between the
>   international code, the country/region code, the area code, the
>   prefix, and the last few numbers.

Edit: I'm not to keen on SQL, so can only offer more Excel focused ideas :/

Comment: I've found from experience that the best method is to bring the data into the worksheet in as raw a state as possible and deal with any pretty formatting issues once you have real dates and real numbers in the worksheet so this is a spot on response (imho).